# Cannot connect to jcenter() in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle, jcenter

I'm trying to import [MusicBobber](https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber) library in android studio. I had download and import the example project but when I sync the project this error showed up:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    A problem occurred configuring project ':audiowidget'.
    Could not download support-media-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.0)
    Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/support-media-compat-24.2.0.aar'.  
    Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/support-media-compat-24.2.0.aar'.  
    Connection to 'https://jcenter.bintray.com' refused
```

when I try to open the https://jcenter.bintray.com , site will open with no problem.
also I'm using freegate for proxy.
where is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: The problem is that your access to the **jcenter** is limited. So you should use an appropriate proxy software like _freegate_, _hotspot_ etc. Also you should declare your proxy configuration in the Android Studio, for this purpose, there are different approaches. like _HTTP Proxy_ or configuring the **gradle.properties** file manually.

Comment: I use freegate and proxy settings are set. no difference

Comment: In the "HTTP Proxy" section click on **Check connection** and enter the URL https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/    for test. If everything is alright, then you should see **Connection successful** prompt. Check it.

Comment: no connection, the error is `Problem with connection: no protocol: jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat‌​/…`

Comment: Check this one: [link](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-media-compat/24.2.0/)   Notice that this URL start with _https_ protocol.

Comment: this is ok: `Connection successful`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122090/discussion-between-shima-erfan-and-iman-irajian).

Comment: No. These libraries are not in jcenter but locally in your SDK. Did you update the SDK?

Comment: yes SDK is updated to last versions

Comment: Finally I run the project successfully, please review my solution.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio, go to

> File> Settings...> Appearance & Behavior> System Settings> HTTP Proxy

then choose **Auto-detect proxy settings**

finally *Synchronize* your project.

**Note:**

Make sure your **SDK** and **Android Studio** and **gradle** are update. I run the project successfully with these system's configurations:

- *Android Studio 2.1.3*
- *gradle-2.14.1*
- **SDK:**
- *Android Support Repository 32*
- *Google Play services 32*
- *Android Repository 32*

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`jcenter()` with `maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }`

worked for me.

Comment: It seems like aliyun is a mirror of default maven repository url which is using alibaba cloud, may also improve download speed.